# Combat system in batch

Tags: batch-file

Hi recently i was challenged by a freind to make a space rpg the only thing im having issues with is my combat system its like the board game battleship basically he is a random number between 1-25,that works,i got a radar system to avoid people being able to actually hit the enemy,that works, but the player firing does not it just closes when i press any key

```
 :combatalpha
 cls
 @echo off
 echo Fire where 
 echo 1)1-1
 echo 2)1-2
 echo 3)1-3
 set /a number=%random% %% 25+1
 if '%number%' == '20' (
 echo its between 15-25 )
 if '%number%' == '21' (
 echo its between 20-25 )
 if '%number%' == '22' (
 echo its between 20-25 )
 if '%number%' == '23' (
 echo its between 20-25 )
 if '%number%' == '24' (
 echo its between 20-25 )
 if '%number%' == '25' (
 echo its between 20-25 )
 if '%number%' == '15' (
 echo its between 10-20 )
 if '%number%' == '16' (
 echo its between 15-20 )
 if '%number%' == '17' (
 echo its between 15-20 )
 if '%number%' == '18' (
 echo its between 15-20 )
 if '%number%' == '19' (
 echo its between 15-20 )
 if '%number%' == '10' (
 echo its between 5-15 )
 if '%number%' == '11' (
 echo its between 10-15 )
 if '%number%' == '12' (
 echo its between 10-15 )
 if '%number%' == '13' (
 echo its between 10-15 )
 if '%number%' == '14' (
 echo its between 10-15 )
 if '%number%' == '5' (
 echo its between 0-10 )
 if '%number%' == '6' (
 echo its between 5-10 )
 if '%number%' == '7' (
 echo its between 5-10 )
 if '%number%' == '8' (
 echo its between 5-10 )
 if '%number%' == '9' (
 echo its between 5-10 )
 if '%number%' == '1' (
 echo its between 1-5 )
 if '%number%' == '2' (
 echo its between 1-5 )
 if '%number%' == '3' (
 echo its between 1-5 )
 if '%number%' == '4' (
 echo its between 1-5 )
 echo %number%
 set /p pshot=
 if '%pshot%' == '1' %AND% (
 if '%number%' == '1' (
 echo HIT!
 pause 
 goto combatalpha) ) 
 if '%pshot%' == '2' %AND% (
 if '%number%' == '2' (
 echo HIT!)
 pause 
 goto combatalpha )
 if '%pshot%' == '3' %AND% (
 if '%number%' == '3' (
 echo HIT!
 pause 
 goto combatalpha) 
 if '%pshot%' == '4' %AND% (
 if '%number%' == '4' (
 echo HIT!
 pause 
 goto combatalpha) )
 if '%pshot%' == '5' %AND% (
 if '%number%' == '5' (
 echo HIT!
 pause 
 goto combatalpha) )
 if '%pshot%' == '6' %AND% (
 if '%number%' == '6' (
 echo HIT!
 pause 
 goto combatalpha) )
 if '%pshot%' == '7' %AND% (
 if '%number%' == '7' (
 echo HIT!
 pause 
 goto combatalpha) )
 if '%pshot%' == '8' %AND% (
 if '%number%' == '8' (
 echo HIT!
 pause 
 goto combatalpha) )
 if '%pshot%' == '9' %AND% (
 if '%number%' == '9' (
 echo HIT!
 pause 
 goto combatalpha) )
 if '%pshot%' == '10' %AND% (
 if '%number%' == '10' (
 echo HIT!
 pause 
 goto combatalpha) )
 if '%pshot%' == '11' %AND% (
 if '%number%' == '11' (
 echo HIT!
 pause 
 goto combatalpha) )
 if '%pshot%' == '12' %AND% (
 if '%number%' == '12' (
 echo HIT!
 pause 
 goto combatalpha) )
 if '%pshot%' == '13' %AND% (
 if '%number%' == '13' (
 echo HIT!
 pause 
 goto combatalpha) )
 if '%pshot%' == '14' %AND% (
 if '%number%' == '14' (
 echo HIT!
 pause 
 goto combatalpha) )
 if '%pshot%' == '15' %AND% (
 if '%number%' == '15' (
 echo HIT!
 pause 
 goto combatalpha) )
 if '%pshot%' == '16' %AND% (
 if '%number%' == '16' (
 echo HIT!
 pause 
 goto combatalpha) )
 if '%pshot%' == '17' %AND% (
 if '%number%' == '17' (
 echo HIT!
 pause 
 goto combatalpha) )
 if '%pshot%' == '18' %AND% (
 if '%number%' == '18' (
 echo HIT!
 pause 
 goto combatalpha) )
 if '%pshot%' == '19' %AND% (
 if '%number%' == '19' (
 echo HIT!
 pause 
 goto combatalpha) )
 if '%pshot%' == '20' %AND% (          
 if '%number%' == '20' (             
 echo HIT!                                  
 pause                                 
 goto combatalpha) )                
 if '%pshot%' == '21' %AND% (         
 if '%number%' == '21' (              
 echo HIT!                         
 pause                                 
 goto combatalpha) )                
 if '%pshot%' == '23' %AND% (       
 if '%number%' == '23' (         
 echo HIT!                     
 pause 
 goto combatalpha) )
 if '%pshot%' == '24' %AND% (
 if '%number%' == '24' (
 echo HIT!
 pause 
 goto combatalpha) )
 if '%pshot%' == '25' %AND% (
 if '%number%' == '25' (
 echo HIT!
 pause 
 goto combatalpha) )
 pause
 echo MISS!
 pause
 goto start
```

Comment: sorry, why don't you use `if %pshot%==%number% (echo HIT) else (echo MISS)`?

Comment: Sorry i'm not completely new to batch but a lot pf better methods usually just fly over my head

Answer (score 1):

The main reason for the process end if the`goto start` when the player misses. The label `:start` is not defined.

Just a simplification of your code (sorry, it is really redundant, luckly the range is 1-25). Not sure this is exactly what you are coding, but can be used as a starting point

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "rounds=1"
    set "hits=0"

:combatalpha
    set /a "number=%random% %% 25+1"
    set /a "lowLimit=number / 5 * 5"
    if %lowLimit% equ 25 set "lowLimit=20"
    set /a "highLimit=lowLimit + 5"
    if %lowLimit% equ 0 set "lowLimit=1"

:ask
    cls
    echo round %rounds% hits %hits%
    echo(
    echo it is between %lowLimit%-%highLimit% (it is %number%)
    echo(
    set "pshot=" 
    set /p "pshot=Your shot? " || goto :ask

    if "%pshot%"=="%number%" (
        echo HIT!
        set /a "hits+=1"
    ) else (
        echo MISS!
    )
    set /a "rounds+=1"

    pause
    goto :combatalpha
```

The shot range limits are calculated. The high limit is simply the low + 5 and the low limit is calculated using the fact that in batch files arithmetic operations handle only integers, so, `n/5*5` will round the number to the lower multiple of five (to mimic your ranges). The rest is just paint the interface, ask the player and if the shot matches the position, increment the hit counter. In any case increment the round number and go again to combat.